# Error install ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

```
C:\windows\system32>npm install -g ionic

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\55aaaddb\taco-toolset-6.3.1\ionic -> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\55aaaddb\taco-toolset-6.3.1\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
ionic@2.2.3 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\55aaaddb\taco-toolset-6.3.1\node_modules\ionic
└── @ionic/app-generators@0.0.3

C:\windows\system32>ionic -v
'ionic' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

C:\windows\system32>node -v
v4.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for `npm` folder containing `ionic.cmd`

Add it as a environment variable under `PATH`.
Mine is located under:

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Then try running `ionic -v` again.

Comment: If that worked, hit the tick to mark as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also install ionic-cli through 'npm install -g ionic-cli'

Comment: C:\windows\system32>npm install -g ionic-cli
npm WARN deprecated ionic-cli@0.0.0: If you're looking for the Ionic CLI, install ionic, not ionic-cli
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\55aaaddb\taco-toolset-6.3.1
`-- ionic-cli@0.0.0


C:\windows\system32>ionic
'ionic' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.